# Route Override not working in asp.net core 3.1 razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing

I'm using `Asp.Net Core 3.1 Razor pages`. I need to override the the route for one of the page in my area.

I have `Home` page in my `Area` - `Blog` and the current route is `localhost/blog/home`. I need to change this to `localhost/blog`. I have an `Index` page in the same blog area but it has an route parameter. So it will be `localhost/blog/my-blog-name`. And this will not interfere with `localhost/blog`

I added the setting in `ConfigureServices` in `startup.cs`

```cs
services
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
    {
        options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Blog", "/", "/blog/home");
    });
```

Here is my folder structure,

[image]

But when i navigate to `localhost/blog` I get an `404` not found. Please assist on where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have Home page in my `Area` - `Blog` and the current route is `localhost/blog/home`. I need to change this to `localhost/blog`. I have an `Index` page in the same blog area but it has an route parameter.
>
> when i navigate to localhost/blog I get an 404 not found.

If you check the definition of [AddAreaPageRoute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.addareapageroute?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you can find it takes the name of the area, the name of the page, and the route template, like below.

```
.AddAreaPageRoute("{area_name_here}", "{page_name_here}", "{route_here}")
```

Based on your requirement and code, we can find you do not configure the specified route to the page correctly, and if your `Index` page of Blog area accepts a required (not optional) route parameter, which would cause 404 error while you browse `localhost/blog`.

To fix the issue and achieve the requirement, you can try modify the code like below.

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(
        options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Blog", "/home", "/blog");
        }
    );
```

Test Result

[image]